# Unable to use third party Lib.aar in AOSP

Tags: android, android-source, android-library

I have made a aar library and added path: framework/base/packages/MyLib/MyLib.aar in AOSP.

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MyLib
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_PREBUILT_MODULE_FILE := $(LOCAL_PATH)/MyLib.aar
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

When I add this lib in other application like Settings and it's working fine. But I want to use in framework/base/service/ in some java file. I am getting unable to import class file of that library.

I have added it in other apps Andropid.mk like LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES := MyLib

Answer (score 0):

This is my method to convert prebuilt `aar` to static android lib. It worked fine for me. You can refer this method for your situation.

```
include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
    
######################## TuanPM13 ##################################### 

# add config to convert prebuilt aar to static android lib
#######################################################################
define aar-to-android-lib
$(foreach t,$(1), \
    $(eval include $(CLEAR_VARS)) \
    $(eval tw := $(subst :, ,$(strip $(t)))) \
    $(eval LOCAL_MODULE := $(word 1,$(tw))) \
    $(eval LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional) \
    $(eval LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(word 2,$(tw))) \
    $(eval LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(call intermediates-dir-for,JAVA_LIBRARIES,$(LOCAL_MODULE),,COMMON)/aar/res) \
    $(eval LOCAL_USE_AAPT2 := true) \
    $(eval LOCAL_RENDERSCRIPT_TARGET_API := $(2)) \
    $(eval LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES) \
    $(eval LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_JAVA_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)) \
    $(eval LOCAL_BUILT_MODULE_STEM := javalib.jar) \
    $(eval LOCAL_UNINSTALLABLE_MODULE := true) \
    $(eval include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)) \
)
endef

prebuilt_aar_libraries := exoplayer-core:libs/exoplayer-core-2.10.8.aar \
    exoplayer-ui:libs/exoplayer-ui-2.10.8.aar \
    exoplayer-extension-mediasession:libs/extension-mediasession-2.10.8.aar

$(call aar-to-android-lib, $(prebuilt_aar_libraries), 28) # API level 28

prebuilt_aar_libraries :=
```

Noted that in my case, all *.arr were placed in `libs` directory.
Then in Android.mk of other applications, I link to them like below

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
    
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

...

LOCAL_STATIC_ANDROID_LIBRARIES += \
    exoplayer-extension-mediasession \
    exoplayer-ui \
    exoplayer-core

include $(BUILD_PACKAGE)
```

Comment: Why need to convert it because I am able to use it some application like in Settings, SystemUI etc.

Comment: @D.J I have not known exactly what is wrong in your method yet but my method it is just another way for you to try.